# Getting random characters from a function

Tags: c, random, passwords

I am learning C with a book rn and I'm trying to make a password generator j4f but I dont know how I can get random characters. I also want be able to say how many characters I want & it should be able to be returned from a function.

Comment: *rn*? *j4f*? Looks like you have already got random characters

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is a `rand()` function in C: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm here you have some examples on how to use it.

Comment: @EugeneSh rn = "right now", j4f = "just for fun".

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Thanks. I believe though that one should not look up the urban dictionary when reading SO question...

Comment: On StackOverflow, "j4f" translates to "because I have a homework assignment." Especially from new users with 1 rep.

Comment: @Mike Holt actually no, we dont even have C in class :D I'm doing this at home for myself.

Comment: @Nazaroth you've got your answer now. Hope this helps!

Comment: @EugeneSh. no problem. I guess I'm too young, I didn't even have to think twice about those.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Nice way to say "you are too old" :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ASCII, something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char *randpw(int len) {
    char *tmp = malloc(len + 1); // +1 so there's room for null terminator
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         /*
             choose a character between 32 and 126, inclusive,
             and put the character into the string.
         */
         tmp[i] = (rand() % (126 - 32)) + 32; 
    }
    tmp[len] = '\0'; // include null termination on string.
    return tmp;
}

int main(void) {
    srand( time( NULL));
    char *pwd = randpw(15);
    printf("%s\n", pwd);
    free(pwd);
    return 0;
}
```

Each character will be from 32 to 126. If you look at an ASCII table, you'll see these are reasonable characters to choose from.

This function will allocate memory, and return a string of random characters of whatever length you give it.

Comment: `tmp[i] = (rand() 126 - 32) + 32; ` Didn't U forget a `%`? :)

Comment: @gaazkam yup I totally did, fixed

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to define a string containing all the possible characters you want inside the random password.

```
const char password_chars[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQWXYZ1234567890";
```

Now you want to take a random number to use as an index for this string.
You use a simple trick common with random generator in order to generate a random number between 'a' and 'b' using the modulus:

```
rand() % (b-a+1) + a
```

In your case 'b' is the length of the string containing all the possible characters and 'a' is 0. 
Put it all together in a function and here is how to implement this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

const char password_chars[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQWXYZ1234567890";

char * password_generator( int pwd_length)
{
    char * pwd = malloc( pwd_length + 1);
    for( int i=0; i<pwd_length; i++)
        pwd[i] = password_chars[rand() % strlen(password_chars)];
    pwd[pwd_length] = '\0';

    return pwd;
}

int main()
{
    srand( time( NULL));

    char * password = password_generator( 10);

    printf( "%s\n", password);

    free( password);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't cast your malloc, this isn't C++

Comment: also why return 1?

Comment: Your right, the casting is a bad habit of mine which i struggle to get over. The return 1 also a bad habit for using function returns in if statements.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain "random" integers from a range between `0` and `RAND_MAX` (which is a rather large upper limit specific to implementation) you can use the `rand` function from `stdlib.h`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%i\n", rand());
    return 0;
}
```

([working example](https://ideone.com/g37Jye))

([documentation of rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/))

There is still a problem though: This code will produce the same output each time the program is run. To prevent this we need to seed the random number generator - and [even though this is, strictly speaking, not guaranteed to work](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand), in practice almost every implementation supports seeding the generator with the current time. This boils down to calling `srand(time(0))` (or equivalently `srand(time(NULL))`) before the first (and only the first) call to `rand()`:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        printf("%i\n", rand());
        printf("%i\n", rand());
        return 0;
    }
```

([working example](https://ideone.com/VnUdI3))

([srand documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/))

Try running both above examples a few times and see the difference.

Now how to translate numbers to characters? Almost all implementations code characters in the ASCII encoding ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)). You can easily convert numbers to characters given the conversion table from Wikipedia:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        int i = 68;
        char ch = i;
        printf("%c\n", ch);
        return 0;
    }
```

According to the table, 68 translates to D and indeed this is what is printed: ([working example](https://ideone.com/d7AZTk))

Now I was going to say "your turn now" but apparently the answer above me deals with the rest as well so I won't say it.